# Fixing the iPhone horizontal orientation zoom

Tags: iphone, mobile, orientation, mobile-safari, zooming

My issue is the zoom that occurs when changing the orientation of an iPhone from portrait to landscape. I see this is a pretty well known issue, and there seems to be plenty of documentation on it, but so far, none of the solutions are working for me.

This is my code..

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

I'm still getting the zoom issue with this, even though I've seen people post this code as a solution to the problem, and they seem to be getting the desired results, I'm not.

My goal here is to disable zoom, have it scaled at 1.0, and of course, prevent the zoom that occurs when changing orientation.

I would like to avoid using javascript as well.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [site](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml), the device-width is always the width in portrait. In other words, the device width will always be 320 on an iPhone.

In the meta tag that you posted, you would need to set the `width=device-height` to get the intended results in landscape.

While I haven't tackled this problem myself, according to that same link it looks like you will need to use media queries with the orientation.

Comment: Wouldn't this cause devices to think the width is large than it is when in portrait mode? I've also discovered that the problem is not occuring on an iPad 2. As of now, I'm testing this on an iPhone 5, and an iPad 2.

Comment: Yes, if you simple changed the meta tag then you would have that problem. However, you could try changing it to troubleshoot whether I am correct about that being the issue. Since I don't know the rest of your code I cannot be sure, but I think you will need to use media queries. Is your layout large enough to be limited by the 768 device pixels on the iPad 2?

Comment: I'm using a series of media queries now. The layout fits fine for under 568 width (mobile phones), under 1024 width (tablets), and desktop sizes. As far as I know, there's no way to change the scalability with media queries. Enabling or disabling zoom can only be done with the meta tag.